# Rolling window multi value comparison along a dimension

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

Given a dimension, n and boolean operator, I want see if given tensor with appropriate dimensions compares with (i + 1)th to (i + n)th slice along the given dimension by applying the operator.

In other words, in a more specific case, say I have an array of 2 dimensions and I want to compare 5 values. I need to create a boolean array where the 1st row will have in the 1st column true if all the next 5 values are higher than the 1st value. Similarly across the columns and the next rows, which the 1st column will have the comparison of values in the 1st column of row 3 to 8 with that or the 1st column in row 2.

E.g.

```
[[1, 1],
 [2, 2],
 [3, 3],
 [4, 4],
 [5, 5],
 [6, 0],
 [7, 1],
 [8, 2]]
```

should give:

```
[[True, False],
 [True, False],
 [True, False]]
```

When the operator is `all >=` (which entails that all next 5 items should be greater than or equal) and number of items to compare is 5 and the comparison is row wise (axis 0).

I want to do this in Numpy or Pandas but prefer Numpy.

Comment: Could you, please, provide an example with a certain tensor (2-dimensional array, for instance) and desired output?

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick would be using [`Scipy's 1D minimum filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter1d.html) and comparing the current element against the minimum of the interval starting one after the current one and of length `n`. Checking against the minimum in that interval, we are basically checking for `greater-than` against all elements.

Thus, we would have a solution, like so -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import minimum_filter1d as minf

def rolling_comparison(a, W):
    HW = (W-1)//2 # Half window size for offsetting kernel in min filter
    v = minf(a,W,origin=-HW)
    return v[:,1:] > a[:,:-1]
```

Here's a sample test with various window sizes -

```
In [245]: a
Out[245]: 
array([[59, 86, 77, 31, 91, 88, 13, 77, 77, 39],
       [12, 63, 98, 21, 69, 89, 93, 38, 52, 62],
       [29, 58, 42, 74, 22, 27, 23, 40, 37, 11]])

In [246]: rolling_comparison(a, W=3)
Out[246]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False]])

In [247]: rolling_comparison(a, W=5)
Out[247]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])

In [248]: rolling_comparison(a, W=7)
Out[248]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

**Solving sample case**

Now, the listed approach works along each row of a 2D array. It seems you are looking to make it work on per-column basis. Also, the listed approach `reflects` the boundary elements for the boundary, whereas in your case you are interested in the valid elements only. So, to adapt to your case, we need to use `transpose` and clip at first half window size.

Thus, adapting to your case, we would have -

```
In [82]: a
Out[82]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5],
       [6, 6],  # Made the second elem as 6 for variety
       [7, 1],
       [8, 2]])

In [83]: rolling_comparison(a.T, W=5).T[:3] # 3 is half window size for 5
Out[83]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: +1, Many thanks for the answer. This does shed some light, but just wanted to also point out `minf` might not work if the operator is `==`.

Comment: Also `W = 5` and `W = 7` should have progressively lesses elements than `W = 3` case.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena As noted in the post, minimum-filter is exclusively meant to work for greater-than problem. Also, this solution assumes we are working along each row, but in the sample you are doing it along each column. So, to adapt to your case, just transpose it.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena Added a section on solving your case. See if it helps?